# logout a user from the system using a function in python

Tags: python, linux

I am developing a GUI. I have a button that upon clicking it, the system reboot off using:

```py
os.system(reboot now -h)
```

Now I want a similar button that will logout the user.

logout is not a command in Linux and exit just closes the terminal. Is there a way to logout the user completely back to the login screen?

Comment: It depends on the linux distribution (or more specifically the window manager).  An option for Ubuntu with GNOME would be e.g. this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/15795/how-can-you-log-out-via-the-terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following Linux command line:

```
pkill -KILL -u {username}
```

So if you want to logout the user "ahmed", the command will be like this:

```
os.system('pkill -KILL -u ahmed')
```